# Way to scrape a JS-Rendered page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently scraping a list of URLs on my site using the `request-promise` npm module.

This works well for what I need, however, I'm noticing that not all of my divs are appearing because some are rendered after the fact with JS. I know I can't run that JS code remotely to force the render, but is there any ways to be able to scrape the pages only after those elements are added in?

I'm doing this currently with Node, and would prefer to keep using Node if possible.

Here is what I have:

```
const urls ['fake.com/link-1', 'fake.com/link-2', 'fake.com/link-3']

urls.forEach(url => {
  request(url)
    .then(function(html){
      //get dummy dom
      const d_dom = new JSDOM(html);
      ....
    }
});
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? Or if there is currently an alternative to Selenium as an npm module?

Comment: You need to use a headless browser such as [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)

Comment: I see, reading up on it now, if I use Puppeteer to access the pages, as opposed to request, will I have the DOM readily available?

Comment: You will get an HTML string back, so you will then need to parse the string like you are with `JSDOM`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Oh this is perfect, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: use `page.content()` https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v0.13.0/docs/api.md#pagecontent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) which is a Chrome headless browser (owned and maintained by Chrome/Google) for loading and parsing dynamic web pages.

Use `page.goto()` to goto a specific page, then use [page.content()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v0.13.0/docs/api.md#pagecontent) to load the html content from the rendered page.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const urls = ['fake.com/link-1', 'fake.com/link-2', 'fake.com/link-3']

urls.forEach(async url => {
  let dom = new JSDOM(await makeRequest(url))
  console.log(dom.window.document.title)
});

async function makeRequest(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  let html = await page.content()

  await browser.close();
  return html
}
```